# Java - Layout Manager Selection

Tags: java, layout

Is there a simply layout manager I can use in a `JPanel` to create something akin to a bar chart? `FlowLayout` almost meets this need. The added component orientation needs to be left to right (default for `FlowLayout`), but they need to "rest" on the bottom of the panel with excess space at the top (not available in `FlowLayout`). Also, the components will all the be the same height and width.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BoxLayout will do the trick as demonstrated in this [posting](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5395200)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do something like a bar chart, you might want to consider not using `Component`s at all. Just have a single `JComponent` that overrides (IIRC) `paintComponent`. It'll be easier to do the calculations in a manner appropriate to a bar chart rather than trying to use an inappropriate layout manager abstraction.

FWIW, I default to `GridBagLayout`, even if a simpler layout manager will do, on this basis that the code can be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you want in `GridBagLayout`. Yes, I know everyone hates GBL; yes, I know I'll get down-voted. But it really is **not difficult** to understand and you can use it for almost any layout goal.

The trick to get a component to "stick" to the bottom is to use the *anchor* and *fill* properties of the `GridBagConstraints` object properly (i.e. `SOUTH` and `NONE`)

Comment: GridBagLayout is also nice. But I remember that I didnt like it in the beginning as well ;)
Still, in some cases FormLayout generates nicer results when it comes to an actual resize. For example I dont like it when buttons or textboxes change their height. Or can this be set to fix with GBL as well?
Anyway + :)

Comment: Yes - you can make sure a text field or combo box will get no extra vertical spacing by setting its weighty to 0 and its Anchor property to either NONE or HORIZONTAL

Answer (score 0):

A [BoxLayout](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) might work for you.  It lets you layout components left-to-right or top-to-bottom, with the tightly coupled [Box](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html) class to force spacing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer the FormLayout, since it is very flexible but you have to write a lot of code though. And in the beginning its a little bit confusing with its percentage and pixel parameters.

But you can for example tell a control that it is 5 pixels left of another control (thats the main part...it layouts controls in relation to neighbors), then it takes 100% of the lasting space availabel including a border space of 5 pixels (you need to use -5 then).

I think it looks somewhat similar to this

```
FormData data = new FormData();
data.left = new FormAttachement(neighborControl, 5);
data.right = new FormAttachement(100, -5);
...
button.setLayoutData(data);
```

This example is for JFace, but there are Swing implementations as well.
I will look up my old code later this day to check if the code I wrote is right :)

Here´s a additional [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FormLayout.htm)